# Netsuite - How to get 'Text' from a Suitelet dropdown field from POST method

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I want to get the text instead of the value/id from a suitelet dropdown field from Post method. 'context.request.parameters' returns the id, but is there a way in suitescript 2.0 to get the 'text' instead?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find this documented anywhere, but to get the text value for a `select` field in the POST of a Suitelet, you can prepend the field id with `inpt_` (that's intentionally misspelled).

So if your custom field id is `custpage_item`, you can get the text value by calling:

```
var itemName = context.request.parameters['inpt_custpage_item'];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works, but is there a way to do the same in a dropdown field within a sublist of my Suietelet?

Comment: I don't see a way to get the text value from a select in a sublist.  In this case, I would collect all of the ids returned in the sublist, perform a single `search.create` to retrieve the text values you need.  This would only use 10 governance points to get the text value for all data elements in your sublist.